# For Each loop does not look at individual cells for Range.Columns

Tags: vba, excel

I have a function which is passed a series and two ranges as arguments:

```
Call settInnISerie(.SeriesCollection("Toppsuging"), r, langsone.Columns(2))
Sub settInnISerie(srs As Series, xverdier As Range, yverdier As Range)
  Dim c As Range
  Dim i As Long

  srs.XValues = xverdier
  srs.Values = yverdier
  i = 1
  srs.ApplyDataLabels
  For Each c In yverdier.Offset(0, -1)
    If Not IsError(c) And i <= srs.Points.Count Then
      srs.Points(i).DataLabel.Text = "=" & Replace(c.Address(external:=True), "[" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "]", "", 1, -1, vbTextCompare)
    End If
    i = i + 1
  Next c
End Sub
```

However, I get an error on the line inside  the if statement, complaining that "Method 'DataLabel' of object 'Point' failed".

Trying to track down the error, I tried printing out the values of each object used in the loop, and discovered that instead of looping over each cell inside the range offset by one from `yverdier` as I expected, `c` references the whole column on the first passthrough.

**Usually when I use a similar construct this is not the case, why does the `foreach`-loop behave differently in this instance? What is the simplest way to remedy the problem?**

Obviously I can do `for i = 1 to c.rows.count...` but I am puzzled at what to me is bizarre behavior from VBA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is expected behaviour, I think.

You defined `yverdier` as `langsone.Columns(2)` which means that `yverdier` is a collection of `Range` type, with a single column (of multiple cells) in the collection. I think your interpretation is that `yverdier` is a single range comprised of the cells within `langsone.Columns(2)` but there is a subtle difference between the two.

So your `For...Each` loop over the `Range` will iterate each column in the collection (a single columns) and not the `Cells`. I think you would get your desire behaviour if coded:

```
For Each c In yverdier.Offset(0, -1).Cells
```

This example code and debug output shows what I mean in practice - just create a blank workbook and put this code in a `Module`:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim rngSource As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rngSource = Sheet1.Range("A1:D3")

    Debug.Print "Columns:"
    For Each rng In rngSource.Columns
        Debug.Print rng.Address
    Next rng

    Debug.Print "Rows:"
    For Each rng In rngSource.Rows
        Debug.Print rng.Address
    Next rng

    Debug.Print "Cells:"
    For Each rng In rngSource.Cells
        Debug.Print rng.Address
    Next rng

    Debug.Print "No property:"
    For Each rng In rngSource
        Debug.Print rng.Address
    Next rng

End Sub
```

Which will give an output of:

```
Columns:
$A$1:$A$3
$B$1:$B$3
$C$1:$C$3
$D$1:$D$3
Rows:
$A$1:$D$1
$A$2:$D$2
$A$3:$D$3
Cells:
$A$1
$B$1
$C$1
$D$1
$A$2
$B$2
$C$2
$D$2
$A$3
$B$3
$C$3
$D$3
No property:
$A$1
$B$1
$C$1
$D$1
$A$2
$B$2
$C$2
$D$2
$A$3
$B$3
$C$3
$D$3
```